# Regex expression in a variable followed by unknown constant

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
var re = /ABCD-\w{3}/
```

It works as is, but when I use a variable like this:

```
var myvar = "ABCD" + "-\w\\{3}\\}"
var re = nev RegExp(myvar, "g")
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: `var re = /ABCD-\w{3}/` = `new RegExp("ABCD-\\w{3}")`.

Comment: Have you tried `var myvar = 'ABCD' + '-\w{3}'` ? When you already have a variable which is used in a regex constructor, it doesn't matter. It only matters about the string parsing rules of the language, has nothing to do with regex at all ..

Comment: I tried that: var myvar = 'ABCD' + '-\w{3}' but it didn't either.